# Locate saved Wi-Fi password on OpenSUSE Leap 42.3 KDE Plasma

Tags: wifi, kde, opensuse, plasma, kwallet

Where does OpenSUSE Leap 42.3 with KDE Plasma store wireless passwords?

I tried the files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` but there is no `psk` entry in them.

Most likely they are stored in KDE Wallet as it did show up when Wi-Fi was connected for the first time. It offered 2 options of storing passwords: plaintext and some sort of encryption; I selected plaintext with no wallet password. That said, the wifi password must be stored on the system in plain text somewhere. But where?

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to a WPA access point (and using `wpa_supplicant`), then you can find passwords or `psk`s in config files under `/etc/wpa_supplicant/`.